# Move widget with cursor to another layout

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt5, qdockwidget, qtoolbar

I want to simulate QDockWidget/QToolBar behavior for custom widget, unpin widget with `mousePressEvent` from one location and pin it to another location. Like place upper frame to 'sub' location:

[image]

I'm able to unpin it with the following code:

```
class DraggableSpectralFrame(SpectralFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.Window | Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.oldPos = QPointF(self.pos())
        self.local= QPointF(self.pos())
        self.floating = False

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.oldPos = event.globalPos()
        if self.hoverRect.contains(event.localPos()) and \
                event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.floating = True
            self.local = event.localPos()
            self.setParent(None)
            self.show()
            self.move((self.oldPos - self.local).toPoint())


    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.oldPos = event.globalPos()
        if self.floating:
            self.move((self.oldPos - self.local).toPoint())
```

[image]

The problem that I'm loosing pressed functionality after morphing `DraggableSpectralFrame` into window and to move window in a proper way I have to click/press again. Without extra click window still reacts on cursors moves(due to `self.floating` being `True`) but easily looses focus on sharp movements.

May be there is an easier way to implement that idea, if that is the case - please let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to implement dragging and dropping is to use a `QDrag` object to display the widget while dragging. For the widget that should accept the dragged widget you need to set `acceptDrops` to True and reimplement at the very least `dragEnterEvent` and `dropEvent`. Here is a very simple example how this can be done. In this example the "Move me" label can be dragged back and forth between the two windows.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui


class DropFrame(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.vlayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if isinstance(event.source(), DraggableLabel):
            event.accept()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        event.accept()
        widget = event.source()
        if widget:
            self.vlayout.addWidget(widget)


class DraggableLabel(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    def __init__(self, text, parent=None):
        super().__init__(text, parent)
        self.setFrameShape(self.Box)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.drag = QtGui.QDrag(self)
        self.mime_data = QtCore.QMimeData()
        self.drag.setMimeData(self.mime_data)
        # capture image of self to use as pixmap while dragging
        self.pixmap = self.grab()
        self.drag.setPixmap(self.pixmap)

        self.hide()
        self.drag.exec(QtCore.Qt.MoveAction)
        self.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    widget1 = DropFrame()
    label = DraggableLabel('Move me')
    widget1.layout().addWidget(label)
    widget1.show()

    widget2 = DropFrame()
    widget2.show()
    widget2.move(widget1.pos().x(),widget1.pos().y()+150)
    app.exec()
```

Comment: Nice! that's exactly what I was looking for!